# Do we need [read-write] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

While looking at the bad [open](/questions/tagged/open) and [close](/questions/tagged/close) tags, I discovered the [read-write](/questions/tagged/read-write) tag, which has 159 Questions. I think ones related to files can be renamed to [file-io](/questions/tagged/file-io), and the rest, the minority, can simply be removed.

Comment: But then [readonly] will feel lonely )-;